# adding custom code to function addItem in Quote.php

Tags: orders, quote, sales-quote

I looked for a way to add a custom order item.

**Code -> Core -> Mage -> Sales -> Model -> Quote.php**

**See:**

```
   public function addItem(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item $item) {
       // Added: 
       $item->setTrainingLocation($_REQUEST[‘training_location’]);
       //Before: 
       $item->setQuote($this);
   }
```

Now for the above method I have to do changes in Magento core code. How can I do it via an observer or module.

This is what I have tried:

```
    <sales_quote_add_item>
        <observers>
            <addextraid>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>Mour_Customgroup_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>addextraparameter</method>
            </addextraid>
        </observers>
    </sales_quote_add_item>
```

And `observer.php`:

```
    public function addextraparameter($observer) {
        $item = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();
        $item->setCustomId(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('custom_id'));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the event `sales_quote_add_item`. This is dispatched after `$item->setQuote($this);` but this should not be a problem unless you rewritten the `setQuote` method and use the value of training location in that one. I doubt you did this.

[Here is a tutorial](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method) on how to create an observer.

Your method in the observer could look like this:

```
public function methodNameHere($observer) {
    $item = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();
    $item->setTrainingLocation(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('training_location'));
}
```

Comment: what i need to do to make sure item in cart gets updated iff value of training_location is same ??.